# gdb pretty printer for stl throw a "TypeError"

Tags: python, c++, linux, stl, gdb

I followed [STL Support Tools](https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/STLSupport) and find it is not working on my system.
I use gnome Ubuntu 14.04. And I tried this:

```
(gdb) p vct
Python Exception <class 'TypeError'> iter() returned non-iterator of type '_iterator': 
$1 = std::vector of length 20, capacity 32
```

It threw a "TypeError", and only print length and capacity.
My g++ and gdb version:

```
g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2
gdb --version 
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7-0ubuntu3.1) 7.7
```

My .gdbinit:

```
python
import sys 
sys.path.insert(0,'/home/james/bin/gdb_printers/python')
from libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers
register_libstdcxx_printers (None)
end
```

Please help me, thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

> `sys.path.insert(0,'/home/james/bin/gdb_printers/python')`

How did you get `/home/james/bin/gdb_printers/python`?

Assuming you followed (inaccurate) instructions on the wiki, and did this:

```
svn co svn://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/trunk/libstdc++-v3/python
```

you now have pretty-printers that match the *latest* `libstdc++` sources (aka "trunk"), while your `libstdc++` itself is over a year old, and came from `gcc-4.8`.

To get correct pretty-printers, you need to get them from a matching gcc branch. I believe the correct command is:

```
svn co svn://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/branches/gcc-4_8-branch/libstdc++-v3/python
```

Comment: thank you for responding. Your solution does not work on Ubuntu 14.10, which uses python 3 for gdb. I have solve this problem now, and after searching, I found  https://github.com/Manicqin/gdb_printers__python, which can solve my problem perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
git clone https://github.com/Manicqin/gdb_printers__python python
```

This will solve the problem perfectly.

no TypeError and no python 3 problem.

Answer (score 0):

Note that those instructions are really just for folks either in the past (before this stuff was packaged up) or on non-Linux systems.  Your typical modern Linux distro will install these debugging scripts in a way that "just works" without any additional configury on your part.